# Распределение критериев по услугам через многие-ко-многим

Tags: sql, база-данных, связи, многие-ко-многим

Моя задача:
Необходимо разработать БД для Digital компании (сам себе придумал задание), но столкнулся с такой сложностью, что есть разнообразные услуги, у которых есть **общие** критерии (стоимость, исполнитель, заказчик...) и есть **уникальные** (ЦА, бюджет, направление...). Преподаватель предложил два варианта решения: через **суперсущность** и второй вариант через связь многие-ко-многим (где есть сущность *Тип услуги*, в которой хранится ключ и название типа услуги, сущность *Критерии*, где такие же атрибуты и третья сущность - *Распределение*, где хранится ключ, FK тип услуги, FK критерий, **и по моему мнению хранится значение критерия**).
Я выбрал второй вариант как более правильный и столкнулся с тем, что не понимаю, где хранить значение уникального критерия.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Criteria* - сущность с критериями
*ServiceType* - сущность с типом услуги
*ServiceCriterion* - сущность для связи многие-ко-многим

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд вы всё правильно отобразили в диаграмме. Значение критерия действительно можно хранить в т.н. таблице связи

[image: Диаграмма]

**Как идея**: можно вынести общие поля (стоимость, исполнитель, заказчик) в таблицу `service`, тогда некоторые запросы будут чуть короче (но это так, в качестве идеи):

вместо:

```sql
select s.id, s.desc
from service s -- можно делать select from service_criteria 
               -- и джоинить service и criteria
join service_criteria sc on sc.service_id = s.id
join criteria c on c.id = sc.criteria_id
where c.desc = 'Price'
  and CAST(sc.criteria_val AS decimal) < 120.00
```

можно будет:

```sql
select s.id, s.desc
from service
where s.price < 120.00
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. В качестве изображения я привел только интересующую меня часть, а общие критерии и так хранятся в отдельной сущности. А какой тип данных использовать для хранения значения критерия? Varchar? Ведь критерии разнообразные и типы данных у них чисто логически отличаются.

Comment: В реальном проекте, конечно, использование varchar может быть не лучшей идеей, но для учебного проекта вполне себе вариант.
Можно создать, например, несколько вариантов service_criteria, в одной будут целочисленные, в другой с плавающей точкой и в последней текстовые. Можно использовать byte array для типа данных колонки со значением.

Comment: Это будет система, так что должен сойти и varchar. В общем благодарю за совет!